# React client auto redirects to my identityserver4 server

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I have a simple React application and I'm trying to connect it with my identityserver. This react application simply has two pages: `Home` and `My Home`.

1. If you come to my root path (`/`) - which is `Home` page as unauthorize user, you would need to click on the login button and it will take to the log in page in the identity server.
2. Once you are logged in, you will be taken back to `My Home` (`/myHome`)
3. On `My Home` page, you will have an option to call api to get user info and another button to log out

**Issues that I have:**

1. Go to the root path `/` will auto redirect me to the login page in identity server.
2. After signing in (authentication), I will redirected back to the `My Home` page - which is good. However, when I try to get user info, I get the errors on console, saying that profile is null and `No matching state found in storage`

I think that somewhere in the redirect function is messed up or the way that I set it up is not working properly, but I am not sure.

Would love to hear from the SOF community. Thank you

Below are some of my snippet codes:

`App.js`

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from 'oidc-react';
import SigninOidc from "./components/SiginOidc";
import SignoutOidc from "./components/SignoutOidc";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import userManager, { loadUserFromStorage } from './services/userService';
import store from './store';
import MyHome from './components/MyHome';
import Home from './components/Home';

const App = () => {

    useEffect(() => {        
        loadUserFromStorage(store)
    }, [])

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AuthProvider userManager={userManager} store={store}>

                <Routes>                    

                    <Route path='/' element={<Home />}></Route>
                    <Route path='/myHome' element={<MyHome /> }></Route>                    
                    <Route path="/signin-oidc" element={<SigninOidc />}></Route>
                    <Route path="/signout-oidc" element={<SignoutOidc /> }></Route>
                </Routes>                
            </AuthProvider>
        </Provider>
    );

};
export default App;
```

========
`Home.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { signinRedirect } from '../services/userService';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {

    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);

    function login() {

        signinRedirect();
    }

    return (

        (user) ? (<Navigate to='/myHome' />)
            : (
                <div>
                    <h1>Home</h1>
                    <p>Hello stranger, please log in</p>

                    <button className="button button-clear" onClick={() => login()}>Login</button>

                </div>)
    );

}

export default Home;
```

====

`MyHome.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { signoutRedirect } from '../services/userService';
import * as apiService from '../services/apiService';

const MyHome = () => {


    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");


    function logout() {
        
        signoutRedirect();
    }

    async function getUserInfo() {

        const userId = user.profile.sub;
        const profile = await apiService.getUserInfo(userId);

        setName(profile.displayName);
    }

    return (

        <div>
            <h1>Hello member</h1>
            
            <button onClick={() => await getUserInfo() }>Get user name: { name}</button>
            <button onClick={() => logout() }>Logout</button>
        </div>
    );

}

export default MyHome;
```

====

`SigninOidc.js`

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { signinRedirectCallback } from '../services/userService';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function SigninOidc() {
    
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function signinAsync() {
            
            await signinRedirectCallback();
            navigate(`/myHome`);
        }
        signinAsync();
    }, [navigate])

    return (
        <div>
            Redirecting...
        </div>
    )
}

export default SigninOidc;
```

====
`SigninOutOidc.js`

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { signoutRedirectCallback } from '../services/userService';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function SignoutOidc() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function signoutAsync() {
            await signoutRedirectCallback();
            navigate('/myHome');
        }
        signoutAsync();
    }, [navigate])

    return (
        <div>
            Redirecting...
        </div>
    )
}

export default SignoutOidc;
```

====
`userService.js`

```
import { UserManager, WebStorageStateStore } from 'oidc-client';
import { storeUserError, storeUser } from '../actions/authActions'

const config = {
    authority: "http://localhost:5001",
    client_id: "partie.reactwebapp.client",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:44450/signin-oidc",
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: "openid profile gateway_api",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:44450/signout-oidc",
    loadUserInfo: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    acr_values: '',
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),

    metadata: {
        issuer: "http://localhost:5001",
        authorization_endpoint: 'http://localhost:5001/connect/authorize',
        token_endpoint: 'http://localhost:5001/connect/token',
        jwks_uri: 'http://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks',
        userinfo_endpoint: 'http://localhost:5001/connect/userinfo',
        end_session_endpoint: 'http://localhost:5001/connect/endsession'
    }
};

const userManager = new UserManager(config);

export async function loadUserFromStorage(store) {
    try {
        let user = await userManager.getUser();
        if (!user) { return store.dispatch(storeUserError()) }
        store.dispatch(storeUser(user));
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`User not found: ${e}`);
        store.dispatch(storeUserError());
    }
}

export function signinRedirect() {
    return userManager.signinRedirect();
}

export async function signinRedirectCallback() {
    return await userManager.signinRedirectCallback();
}

export function signoutRedirect() {
    userManager.clearStaleState();
    userManager.removeUser();
    return userManager.signoutRedirect();
}

export function signoutRedirectCallback() {
    userManager.clearStaleState();
    userManager.removeUser();
    return userManager.signoutRedirectCallback();
}

export default userManager;
```

Comment: I think whatever issue you have is likely encapsulated in the code you neglected to include in your post. What is `userManager.signinRedirectCallback` doing? Once a user is authenticated how does the app know? Is any of the redux code relevant? See [mcve].

Comment: The `userManager.signinRedirectCallback` is coming from the `oidc-client` library though (https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). That project is archived now....

Comment: Well, that's as far as I can get in the code you've provided before the trail goes cold. I'm sort of asking where the trail picks up again in your code after someone authenticates. You say they are correctly navigate to `"/myhome"`. What is missing there? Something selected from the redux state? If so, how does that state get populated?

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese. After user authenticates, they are redirected back to `/myHome` and I can see that the user object is stored correctly on my local storage. However, attempting to retrieve the `user` object through `useSelector` return a null object. Hence, when the api trying to call with parameter `user.profile.sub` (which is `userId`) fails.

Comment: `useSelector` is a `react-redux` hook and has absolutely nothing at all to do with localStorage. ***Something*** needs to update the redux store if you want to select state values from it. Updating localStorage alone, outside of React won't do anything inside the React app.

Comment: May be that's what I'm missing. I was under the assumption that `useSelector` would auto update the redux store. I'll look into that. Thank you

Comment: No, it's kind of the other way around, actions are dispatched to the store to update it, `useSelector` only picks parts of the current state.